# Anita can paint the shed in 5 hours. If Kris helps her, they can paint the shed in 3 hours. How long would it take Kris to paint the shed alone?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Anita can paint the shed in 5 hours. If Kris helps her, they can paint the shed in 3 hours. How long would it take Kris to paint the shed alone?
Please, explain and use a chart if possible.

Comment: Hint: How many sheds can Anita paint in 15 hours, and how many sheds can Kris and Anita working together paint in 15 hours?

Comment: Alt. hint: Anita alone can paint $1/5^{th}$ of a shed in an hour. Both of them can paint $1/3^{rd}$. What fraction of a shed could Kris alone paint in an hour?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Let the total units of work be 15 (LCM of 3 and 5). If Anita finishes the work in 5 hours, it means she does 3 units of work each hour. Together with Kris, they do 5 units of work each hour. So, how many units of work does Kris do each hour?